# AWS Quicksight aggregate data

Tags: amazon-quicksight

i have a dataset like this

Order

| id | expected date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11-04-2022 |
| 2 | 10-04-2022 |
| 2 | 14-04-2022 |

Order Event

| Id | Order Id | Order status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | created | 01-04-2022 |
| 2 | 1 | completed | 12-04-2022 |
| 3 | 2 | created | 01-04-2022 |
| 4 | 2 | in progress | 07-04-2022 |
| 5 | 2 | completed | 10-04-2022 |
| 6 | 3 | created | 10-04-2022 |

and i need to create a graph that show, for all order with completed status the difference between expected date and actual order date.
How can i archueve that

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to join both of the tables into one because QuickSight can only work with multiple data files if they are merged. You can apply an inner join on the order ID.

Then, you can calculate the difference between the expected date and the order date and add an if-statement to filter out the orders who are not completed yet. You do this by adding a calculated field to your dataset with the following code:

```
ifelse(

{Order_status}="completed",
dateDiff({expected_date},{Date},"DD"),
0

)
```

You can also modify this field. Here, I wrote `"DD"` for the date difference in days, you can also select hours etc.. Also, if the order is not completed, I selected `0` as a default value. To find out more about the commands used in this calculated field, visit this AWS Docs links:

[If-Else Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/ifelse-function.html)

[Date-Diff Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/dateDiff-function.html)

Now that the calculated field is created, you can plot it together with the order ID.

BR mylosf

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips.
unfortunately, i need more help :D 
I have another table linked to order, and when quicksight create a the final table i have multiple instance of the same event and when i create a table with average response time i get an uncorrect value (i checked using an sql query on the orignal data)
There is a way to get the average using only the "unique" value?